# how to resize popup of wxcombobox

Tags: c++, combobox, wxwidgets

I have created a combobox on a dialog using wxwidgets C++ library (with MSVC and GCC). The list of items in the combobox are too many and when I click on the combobox whole list is shown on the screen and it looks bad and choosing an item from this list is not that user frendly.

Is there anyway we can see this list in a small popup window with a scrollbar? I could not find any relevant methods to set the size for popup window.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harik

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the desired size in the constructor?

Something like this, which will restrict the height of the popup to 50 pixels

```
int ComboboxHeightPixels = 50;
new wxComboBox( this, ComboID, L"",wxPoint(-1,-1),
    wxSize(-1,ComboboxHeightPixels));
```

Comment: It changes the size of combobox's textbox size, but not the popup size.

Comment: OK, edit your question so it says you tried that and explain how it did not work.  Then I can delete this 'answer'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [wxComboCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxcomboctrl.html) with some popup window (see [wxPopupWindow](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.4/classwx_popup_window.html)) that provides a [wxListView](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxlistview.html) and a resizing method (you probably have to implement that yourself).